# Set custom page title with hook

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I'm trying to set a custom page title (`<title></title>`) with `wp_title`.

The simplest function in the world:

```
function sweety_page_title($string)
{
    echo $string . ' - ';
}
```

After I call:

```
do_action('wp_title', 'my title...');
add_action('wp_title', 'sweety_page_title', 10, 1);
```

But it does not work.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

First make sure you don't have any SEO plugins installed that may also filter your title. Then try this in your functions.php file:

```
add_filter('wp_title','sweety_page_title',10,1);

function sweety_page_title($title){
    $title='Your new title'; //define your title here
    return $title;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For changing page titles, you should hook into *document_title_parts*:

```
function wpdocs_filter_wp_title( $title, $sep ) {

    $title['site'] = 'My Site Title';
    $title['tagline'] = 'My Site Tagline';

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'wpdocs_filter_wp_title', 10000, 2 );
```

Also, if you need more details, checking this file out might help:

*\wp-includes\general-template.php: wp_get_document_title()* method

Answer (score 2):

```
add_filter('wpseo_title','custom_seo_title',10,1);

function custom_seo_title(){
    $title='Your new title'; //define your title here
    return $title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<?php add_filter( 'wp_title', 'filter_function_name', 10, 3 ) ?>`

look at this http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference
there is all hooks check.

get the variable `$var=add_filter( 'wp_title', 'filter_function_name', 10, 3 );` now call ur function, `sweety_page_title($var)`

Comment: I have set a page as home-page and when I use is_home() inside the hook it does not work...does anyone know why?